# Ignoring uppercase and lowercase on char when comparing

Tags: java, string, char

The goal of this is to get a sentence from the user and determine how many of each vowel shows up.The majority of this is done except I am not sure how to ignore uppercase and lowercase letters but I am guessing equalsIgnoreCase or toUpperCase().

I'd like to also know if there is another way to do this  using some other classes of `String`, `StringBuilder`, or `Character`. I'm still new to programming and this chapter is killing me.

```
    int counterA=0,counterE=0,counterI=0,counterO=0,counterU=0;
    String sentence=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a sentence for vowel count");        

    for(int i=0;i<sentence.length();i++){
        if(sentence.charAt(i)=='a'){
            counterA++;}
        else if(sentence.charAt(i)=='e'){
            counterE++;}
        else if(sentence.charAt(i)=='i'){
            counterI++;}
        else if(sentence.charAt(i)=='o'){
            counterO++;}
        else if(sentence.charAt(i)=='u'){
            counterU++;}
        }   
    String message= String.format("The count for each vowel is \nA:%d\nE:%d\nI:%d\nO:%d\nU:%d",
            counterA,counterE,counterI,counterO,counterU);  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
```

}

code here

Comment: `if (theChar == 'a' || theChar == 'A')`?

Comment: Character.toLowerCase(sentence.charAt(i))=='a')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are comparing on primitive char,

```
Character.toLowerCase(sentence.charAt(i))=='a'      
Character.toUpperCase(sentence.charAt(i))=='A'
```

should already be the best way for your case in Java.

But if you are comparing on Stirng

```
 sentence.substring(i,i+1).equalsIgnoreCase("a")
```

will be more direct , but a little bit harder to read.

If you have a String type inside an array or list, calling

```
s.equalsIgnoreCase("a")
```

will be much better. Please note that you are  now comparing with "a" not 'a'.

If you are using `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`, you can call `toString()`, and then use the same method.

```
sb.toString().substring(i,i+1).equalsIgnoreCase("a");
```

Comment: tysm for your info! I was also wondering if "indexOf" could have done the trick? That was my first attempt but I failed.

Comment: @ben ,no. It only returns the **index** within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character. The param of indexOf(int ch) is a char, not a index. And the return value is an index .

Comment: So it's not possible to use a for loop because it always returns the first occurrence and won't go through the rest of a string? Sorry, last question I promise!

Comment: @ben, of course it is possible, it depends on how you operate on the String, for example, in the first loop, the indexOf returns 4, then you can remember this index call soFar, the next loop, you can call (string.subString(soFar,s.length)).indexOf(...). Something like this, it depends on what you want and how you do. But always, we should choose the most readable way and easy way.

Answer (score 2):

equalsIgnoreCase or toUpperCase() method is the best (and the easiest) option.

Comment: Solution, provided by @Jaskey is also OK. You can convert the whole sentence to upper (or lower) case and compare char by char. The other option is converting char by char to upper (or lower) case and then compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `equalsIgnoreCase` looks like it is more readable than converting both Strings to `uppercase` before a comparison. Readability trumps micro-optimization.

below looks more readable

```
if (myString.toUpperCase().equals(myAnotherString.toUpperCase())) {
```

or

```
if (myString.equalsIgnoreCase(myAnotherString))
```